# nginx try_files with rewritten data

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, fastcgi

I require to remove a prefix from the request of the form `METHOD /prefix/some/route/with?params=and&query=string` and then pass it to fastcgi block.

When I say:

```
location /prefix {
    rewrite /prefix/(.*)$ /$1 last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ ^/index.php(/|$) {
    ...
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$
    ...
}
```

Nginx responds with 404, as if the `index.php` was never attached.

If I change the prefix block to:

```
location /prefix {
    rewrite ^/prefix/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
}
```

The `index.php` is hit outside of the fastcgi block and my symfony app resolves the route in the wrong way (with `/prefix/` still present) from `REQUEST_URI` instead of (absent) `PATH_INFO`.

I'm going for the ease of subconfiguration for deployment. How to hit the fastcgi block after the rewrite, with **the least possible modification** of the [minimal nginx:php-fpm combo](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/#connecting-nginx-to-php-fpm) (i.e. from other block)?

Comment: If you want `rewrite` to use the current `location`, end it with `break` instead of `last`. Also, your rewrite rule adds two leading `/`s.

Comment: @RichardSmith, no dice. It behaves exactly the same.